# Unexpected result in RPAD

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle 11g. I am using the Scott account and the demo `EMP` table. I inserted one record with `ENAME` BRUCE WILLIAM. My aim is to show the first name and last name in two columns. I used this code:

```
select trim rpad(ename, instr(ename,' ')))   "First Name", 
       trim(substr(ename, instr(ename,' '))) "Last Name" 
  from emp;
```

This gives a weird result. The `First Name` is extended to second line. I used

```
select trim(substr(ename, 1, instr(ename,' '))), 
       trim(substr(ename, instr(ename, ' '))) 
  from emp;
```

I got the expected output. My question is why the first line of query is giving extra spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting extra spaces in your string, and if you were then the `trim()` would remove them again. SQL*Plus is just formatting the results in a way you don't expect. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#sthref578) mentions the default formatting for column types, and can usually work it out for system functions (though the characterset can make it bigger than you expect).

It *seems* like SQL*Plus, and SQL Developer, can't determine a sensible default for your `rpad` case, but can for your `substr`. Well, SQL*Plus is really just getting a result set cursor from the database, and using the cursor metadata to determine the default widths to apply to the fields for display, so it isn't getting the length you expect from that metadata. But what length should it use?

The database only knows how big the `rpad` value can be if the padding length is a simple value - it doesn't even mind zero (it returns null, which you're relying on). If the padding length is determined by a function then there's no way to tell how big the result could be, apart from calculating it for every value in the result set *before* returning the metadata and and actual data, which isn't practical, and would produce inconsistent output as the data changed.

It also wouldn't be practical to try to determine a theoretical maximum, even though it looks superficially straightforward in your case. `substr` can't ever return something longer than the original value; but `rpad` could potentially produce something huge even from a short input value, so it has to allow for that possibility if it can't easily determine a limit (i.e. from a fixed value).

So it plays safe and allows for it being up to the maximum length for a `varchar2`, which is 4000 characters, as this dynamic SQL demonstrates:

```
declare
    l_curid integer;
    l_desctab dbms_sql.desc_tab3;
    l_colcnt integer;
begin
    l_curid := dbms_sql.open_cursor;

    dbms_sql.parse(l_curid, 'select rpad(ename, instr(ename,'' '')), '
        || 'rpad(ename, 4), '
        || 'substr(ename, 1, instr(ename,'' '')) '
        || 'from emp where ename like ''B%''' , dbms_sql.native);

    dbms_sql.describe_columns3(l_curid, l_colcnt, l_desctab);

    for i in 1 .. l_colcnt loop
        dbms_output.put_line('column ' || i
            || ' ' || l_desctab(i).col_name
            || ' type ' || l_desctab(i).col_type
            || ' length ' || l_desctab(i).col_max_len
        );
    end loop;

    dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_curid);
end;
/

column 1 RPAD(ENAME,INSTR(ENAME,'')) type 1 length 4000
column 2 RPAD(ENAME,4) type 1 length 16
column 3 SUBSTR(ENAME,1,INSTR(ENAME,'')) type 1 length 40
```

As you can see, it knows the length for a fixed-length `rpad` and a `substr` (note the size is four times the actual string length due to the multibyte characterset), but falls back to the maximum for the `rpad` using a function.

What you're seeing is SQL*Plus showing a 4000-char column. If you did this in SQL Developer you would see the header for that column is indeed 4000 characters. SQL*Plus helps a bit by reducing the displayed column header to the [line size](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#sthref1903), and wraps the next column onto a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

```
lpad ('string', n [, 'string_pad')
rpad ('string', n [, 'string_pad')
```

string is left padded to length n with string_pad. If string_pad is ommited, **a space will be used as default**
rpad is similar, but pads right instead of left.

from http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/rpad.html

and here is good example for understanding

```
begin

  for i in 1 .. 15 loop
    dbms_output.put_line(
      rpad('string', i) || '<'
    );
  end loop;

end;
```

Comment: Ok I got why and how **Spaces are used** but my question is how to know how many spaces are used?

Comment: @user1865284 hm..may be so in your case: quant_space := (abs(instr(ename,' ') - length(ename)) + instr(ename,' ') - length(ename))/2; if quant_space > 0 it will be quantity of spaces